# Script sort MP4 (and other) videos by orientation to portrait and landscape folders >>> IMPOSSIBLE?

Tags: macos, video, filesystems, script, shell-script

I've been wrestling with a 14TB+ video library for the last months trying to dedupe and sort all of it into production ready folder structure.

For the life of me I have not been able to find (spent 3 solid days with no sleep) a script that will sort a folder of video files, using their dimensions, into Portrait and Landscape folders.

The closest I've found is this -

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob

for f in *.{mp4,MP4,mov,MOV,m4v,M4V}
    do 
        height=`mdls -raw -name  kMDItemPixelHeight "$f"`
        width=`mdls -raw -name  kMDItemPixelWidth "$f"`
        mkdir -p "${height}x${width}"
        mv "$f" "${height}x${width}"/
        
        printf "File: $f\n"     
        printf "> Dimensions: $height x $width \n\n"
    done

printf "All done! \n"
```

Which gets me closer by sorting them into folders based on dimensions, but it's not what I'm trying to achieve.

Alternatively I found this script for images using Imagemagick, (which I installed via Homebrew) it does read the files, though it moves them ALL into the portraits directory. I'm assuming the variables may be different to extract height and width from a video file?

```
#/bin/zsh
mkdir -p portraits
mkdir -p landscapes
for f in ./*.mp4
do
  r=$(identify -format '%[fx:(h/w)]' "$f")
  if [[ r < 1.0 ]] 
  then
      echo "Portrait detected."
  mv "$f" ./portraits/
  elif  [[ r > 1.0 ]]
  then
  echo "Landscape detected."
      mv "$f" ./landscapes/
  fi
done
```

If someone has another solution using folder actions or automator or ANYTHING else. I'm running Mac OS with terminal.

Comment: `[[ r < 1.0 ]]` and `[[ r > 1.0 ]]` in the second script are kinda amusing. `<` and `>` inside `[[ ]]` compare strings, not numbers. `r` is just a string, not a variable. Neither test depends on the variable, this is why "it moves them ALL into the portraits directory" (although in my case it would be "ALL into the landscapes", string comparison depends on the locale). If there were `-lt` and `-gt` instead of `<` and `>` respectively, then `zsh` couldn't treat `r` as a string, it would evaluate the variable.

Comment: I'm a fan of the ffmpeg package, which includes the ffprobe utility which will fetch video dimensions.  Output is a bit of a mess, though, so it will be difficult to process it, but you can definitely get the dimensions.